# Certain HTML entities (arrows) are not rendered in PDF (iText)

Tags: c#, html, itext, xmlworker

I tried to render `&rArr; &hArr; &euro; &copy; &rarr;` in the HTML with the XMLWorker and iText. Only the copyright and euro symbol appear in the PDF. I used the dafault font and Arial but without success.

Is there a way to get those entities rendered? Is there an alterantive way to render arrows in text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [ParseHtml3](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/ParseHtml3) example, it works for me:

[image]

This is my code to create the PDF:

```
public void createPdf(String file) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    String str = "<html><head></head><body style=\"font-size:12.0pt; font-family:Arial\">"+
            "<p>Special symbols: &larr;  &darr; &harr; &uarr; &rarr; &euro; &copy;</p>" +
            "</body></html>";

    XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
    worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
    // step 5
    document.close();
}
```

Note that all entities are written in lower-case.

Comment: I had a typo in the style was using the default font all the time. It works as you described. It is a font dependent effect.

Comment: Yes, the default font is Helvetica and Helvetica doesn't know how to write those special symbols. That explains the problem. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: what about other entities that don't have a name? They seem to not work

Comment: @user3137043 Please post a new question, and indicate if you are still using the old iText (and XML Worker) or the brand new release of [pdfHTML](http://itextpdf.com/blog/pdfhtml-launch-announcement). Avoid using wording such as *it doesn't work* because it will be embarrassing for you if it turns out that *it does work*.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie 1) the question is about XML worker 2) I said "seem to not work". This means that if you know that it does work with XML worker, please, post an example

Comment: @user3137043 This question has been answered and accepted in 2015. Do not hijack it to post a follow-up question. Also take into account that support for XML Worker will be discontinued soon, so you might want to switch to the newer version. I have written dozens examples that work, but I haven't seen an example that doesn't work (unless the font didn't have the glyphs that were needed), so it's up to you to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem. That's how it works on SO; don't expect me to make an exception for an anonymous user.

Comment: I had this problem and my search led me to this post. If XML worker is outdated, it might make sense to update the answer. But I am not into debating, do whatever you think is best! Thank you for your comments, I have learned about pdfHTML